# html_safe is not working in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb, html-safe

I am using [ckeditor](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor) to save posts content. If I save anything in my db then it saves content with html tags. To escape html i am using `<%= raw(posts.content) %>` function. I am using [Speak.js](https://github.com/kripken/speak.js) for adding functionality to listen posts content also. Here i am doing like this ...

```
<script src="speakClient.js"></script>
<img src="img/listenpost.png" alt="Listen Post" onclick="speak('<%= posts_item.content.html_safe %>')" style="cursor:pointer;" />
```

but here it speaks content with html tags. I tried to do like this also

```
 speak('<%== posts_item.content %>') or  speak('<%= raw posts_item.content %>')
```

But nothing works for me. How can I escape html tags so that **my posts audible without HTML tags**

Comment: `speak('<%== posts_item.content %>')` - There should be only one equal sign after the `%` (`<%=`)

Comment: `speak('<%== posts_item.content %>')` or `speak('<%= raw posts_item.content %>')` both works same

Comment: My mistake. I'm used to only putting down one equal sign

Answer (score 2):

You should escape also inside javascript. Using [`escape_javascript`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper/escape_javascript) helper

```
speak('<%=j posts_item.content.html_safe %>')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I tried this in my html.erb file, its not working

Answer (score 0):

You state that you have tried `speak('<%= raw posts_item.content %>')`. The correct use of the raw helper method in this case would be `<%= raw(posts_item.content) %>` (note that `posts_item.content` is inside parentheses

Comment: Ruby give facility to escape parentheses also. But I tries to put this also, not working